# Raspberry Pi Broadcast Hostname

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, remote, vnc

I am trying to connect to my Raspberry Pi (rPi) via remote connection using the Ethernet. I can connect to my rPi by typing ***raspberrypi.mshome.net*** where *raspberrypi* is the device hostname. I want to connect by typing ***raspberrypi.local*** instead. And I know it's possible since I saw people use it this way.

After hours of digging, I think its probably because the WiFi connection is being shared with the Ethernet and so is the *mshome.net* extension. Is there any way of making it *local*.

Thanks in advance. Looking for solutions with explanations.

[Note: Everything works fine. Its just the huge hostname that bugs me. I'm against installing any softwares and do it with a few tweaks.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.local` is normal [Zero-conf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking) networking.

`.mshome.net` is a Microsoft foible so has nothing to do with the Pi.

Comment: Is there any work around of this in Windows?

Comment: You should ask on a Windows forum (I gave up on Windows 7 years ago). It does work on some; look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local but as I said this is not a problem on the Pi or any Linux system. I believe installing `bonjour` does provide a solution - even when I used Windows (up to XP) I used `bonjour` and it certainly does no harm.